# How to change the style of the last item in ItemSource with WPF and XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an app that is written using c# and WPF on the top of Prism 6.

I am trying to display a breadcrub for the user so they can click the previous link to go back to the previous page. I want the breadcrub to look like so

**Home** >> **Grand Parent Category** >>  **Parent Category** >> *Child Category*

So the "Home", "Grand Parent Category" and "Parent Category" all are clickable and followed by ">>" symbol. But the last item (i.e. "Child Category") is not clickable and does is not followed by the ">>" symbol.

Here is what I have done using `XAML`

```
<!-- Breadcrubs -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BreadcrumbScreenCategories}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- This is the clickable style which is applied on all items -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}"
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
                                                        Path=DataContext.SelectBreadcrumbCategory}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Padding="0 7">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text=" >> "
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

The problem with my code is that every category is clickable and it is followed by the ">>" symbol.

Question, How can I change the style of the last item?

Here is the

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this would be not to change the style, but to hide the >> element for the last item by a binding over a visibility converter. And also disable the last button - again, over a binding.
So, your VM items (items of the ItemsSource) provide a property like `IsClickable` and it's set to `true` for all items, but the last one.